# how to get parents records using .Net Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have datatable called dt

in this table there are records

```
ID Code  FullTxt ParentID
1  A     Tom     NULL
2  A1    John    1
3  A2    Rich    1
4  A11   Carol   2
5  A12   Nancy   2
6  A21   Ali     3
7  B     Mark    NULL
```

When user search for A21 I filter dt to find A21 and then send it as an updated datatable

here is my code

```
    DataTable dx = null;
    var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => x["FullTxt"].ToString().Contains(SearchTxt) 
        || x["Code"].ToString().Contains(SearchTxt)
        );

    if (rows.Any())
        dx = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

I need to include parents records in this filter

If user searched for A21

Then these records should be included in the filtered results

```
ID Code  FullTxt ParentID
1  A     Tom     NULL
3  A2    Rich    1
6  A21   Ali     3
```

I tried updating my code to this but it does not work

```
    var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => x["FullTxt"].ToString().Contains(SearchTxt) 
        || x["Code"].ToString().Contains(SearchTxt) || x["ID"] = x["ParentID"] 
        );
```

Any idea how to get that working?

Comment: You could just get the record that matches your search, and then recursively get it's parents and concatenate the results. That's only a partial LINQ solution, but should be simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => searchText.Contains((string)x["Code"])).ToList();
```

Where x.Field < string >(1) is targeting your second column ("Code") which contains string values.

To specifically get all parent IDs from the search, something like:

```
var parentRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["ParentID"] != DBNull.Value && searchText.Contains((string)x["Code"])).Select(x => (int)x["ParentID"]).ToList();
```

You were on the right track!